# Entity Framework Core: table without primary key

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I have an existing Oracle database with a table that does not have any primary key. I am using Entity Framework Core database-first approach to generate the classes and the `DbContext`, but I am not able to generate it since a table does not have primary key.

Is there any way it can be generated so that it can be used in EF Core?

Comment: Give it a primary key? ;)

Comment: That is not a solution, EF Core supports this, but you may need to intervene, that is, modify the code after it was generated, using partial classes and a OnModelCreating method.